# Uncolour past dates and colour only the current one

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA code which displays with a blue colour the entire column where the today's date is located. The problem I have now is that my code does not uncolour the past dates. That means the colour of the past dates and the today's date is the same. I want only one column to be coloured which is the column of the today's date. I do not want for the past dates to have the same colour with the today's date. Current code below:

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim CellToShow As Range
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
    x = Day(Date)
    Set CellToShow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(3).Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues) 'my dates are located across row 3
    CellToShow.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = RGB(151, 228, 255) 'background colour in the selected cell
    If CellToShow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Cell for day " & x & " found.", vbCritical
    Else
        With CellToShow
            .Select
            .Show 'Scroll the window to show the cell
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the image of the problem.As you can see, Excel does put a colour in the column that contain the today's date. But also already colours the yesterday's date. I do not want yesterday's date been coloured.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBf9P.png

Comment: Have you considered to use conditional formatting instead of code?

Comment: I considered it yes. But I found some VBA codes that I could understand more easily.

Comment: The vba you have colours in one column, but it doesn't ever un-colour any other columns. Assuming you save the changes when you close, this is why they stay coloured (and this is why we suggest conditional formatting, which recalculates every time rather than fixing/saving a colour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Conditional formatting - set 'Applies To' to be the whole worksheet `$1:$1048576`, and the formula to be `=A$3=DAY(TODAY())`. All the vba has to do is the message box if no relevant date is found, and scroll to the relevant column.
**EDIT:**
The reason this will work is because conditional formatting formulas are written for the first (top-left) cell in the range to be formatted (so for the whole sheet, this formula is written how it would apply to cell A1. The formula is then applied to other cells in the range in the same relative way - hence the use of `A$3`, the `$` fixes it to always refer to row 3, while the A is left to change dynamically for each cell to be coloured. In this way the formula applies to whole columns, because the row reference is fixed.

Comment: I tried to integrate the formula but it seems that nothing happens. I am using the formula  `=DAY($3:$3)=TODAY()` because my date data is located in row 3. I then applied it to the whole worksheet but no colour is changing.

Comment: Formula needs to be `=TRUNC(A3)=TODAY()` - `DAY` will get the day of the month

Comment: Still, nothing changed.

Comment: @FunThomas are you sure it needs `TRUNC`?, `DAY` in excel formula does the same as vba `Day` function in the code example given.

Comment: Nik, firstly your formula `=DAY($3:$3)=TODAY()` will not work, please see my edit to the answer. Secondly, can I check you have also entered the desired format (colour) against the conditional formatting rule, not just the formula?

Comment: Day(06-Jun-2022) gives 6, and that's not the same as TODAY. You need Trunc to get rid of the time part.

Comment: @FunThomas I've realised what I did wrong - I meant to put the `DAY()` function on the other part of the formula; `A$3 = DAY(TODAY())`. That should do the same as the vba do you think? From the vba it looks like row 3 only contains day numbers not dates as such

Comment: In theory this works - but only if your dates are from the same month. If you have a sheet with dates from several monthes, it will fail because it would mark also the 6-May or 6-Apr

Comment: @SpencerBarnes These are the steps I followed to integrate your suggestions: Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a Formula which cells to format -> Formula: Your suggestions -> Applies to -> Your suggestion -> Show Formatting rules for: This worksheet -> OK. After these steps, I can not see any difference in my worksheet. Maybe doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned how to add in the desired formatting (colour cell blue)

Comment: Conditional Formatting -> Manage rules -> edit the rule -> Click 'Format' button bottom right -> 'Fill' tab -> select  background colour

Comment: @FunThomas When using the `TRUNC` it colours only the first row of the column in which the today's day is located.

Comment: In the same section (other than fill) you can also edit text colour, font, cell borders and other formatting options

Comment: Regarding your question about `Trunc` see my reply to his comment (and the edit to my answer), about using absolute row reference `A$3` instead of `A3`

Comment: @SpencerBarnes I figured out what I was doing wrong. The VBA code was activated and somehow prevented the conditional formatting operate properly.